# ngFor behavior inside a <form>

Tags: angular, angular2-template, ngfor

I'm learning about Angular2 & RxJS observables.  I created a simple form that displays results of a simulated http.get and *should* allow the user to create a new item.

I used unshift() to accomplish this (as opposed to push()) because i wanted to add the new item to the top of the array referenced by ngFor, and by extension to the top of the displayed list of items, but when i use this approach I see some unwanted behavior.  The first item of the existing output is modified when the new item is added to the array.

As I said, I'm just learning, so pls be patient if i've missed something obvious, but could someone help me understand what's happening here?  I created this plunk to illustrate my issue.  Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

https://embed.plnkr.co/FGi1ot/

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'demo',
template: `
    <button (click)="createItem()">Create</button>
    <button (click)="getItems()">Reset</button>

<form>
    <div class="form-group" *ngFor="let item of items; let i=index"  >
        <div style="padding-top: 50px;">
            <div class="col-xs-4">
                <label id="itemIdLabel-{{i}}" for="itemIdDiv-{{i}}">Id</label>
                <div id="itemIdDiv-{{i}}">{{item.id}}</div>                                                        
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-8">
                <label id="itemNmLabel-{{i}}" for="itemNmInput-{{i}}">Name</label>
                <input id="itemNmInput-{{i}}" name="itemNmInput-{{i}}" [(ngModel)]="item.nm" type="text" class="form-control">
            </div>

            <div class="row" style="padding-top: 10px;">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <button (click)="deleteItem(item.id, i)">Delete</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</form>
`,
})

export class DemoComponent implements OnInit{
items = new Array<Item>();

constructor() {}

ngOnInit(){
    this.getItems();
}

getItems(){
  this.initItems();
}

createItem(){
  //create a new item without an id.  this will be committed once required fields are filled

  //this works fine
  //this.items.push(new Item("new", "newItem"));

  //this does not
  this.items.unshift(new Item("new", "newItem"));
}

deleteItem(id, index){
  this.items.splice(index,1);
}

  initItems(){
    //simulating data coming back from a web service call with ids intact
    this.items.length = 0;
    this.items.push(new Item("first", "firstItem"));
    this.items[0].id = '001';

    this.items.push(new Item("second", "secondItem"));
    this.items[1].id = '002';

    this.items.push(new Item("third", "thirdItem"));
    this.items[2].id = '003';

  }
}

export class Item {
public id: string;

constructor(public nm: string,
public dsc: string){}
}
```

Comment: Please put a [mcve] *in the question*.

Comment: Note the **M** and the **C** - are the details of the `Item`, the `ItemService`, the full HTML markup all relevant? Either cut them out or include them.

Comment: here you are Jon.  This is somewhat more crisp.  Appreciate you taking the time to look at my question.

Comment: This may be a genuine bug which needs to be filed at https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/ if you put `{{item.dsc}}` somewhere in your loop you can see it correctly evaluate that expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, after more research into ngFor and looking through the closed bugs I managed to put together the missing pieces. I'm posting the answer in hopes that it might help others avoid this issue.  It's documented (sort of) in the ngFor api, so i don't think it classifies as a bug per se.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgFor-directive.html

The problem has to do with change tracking.  It seems that ngFor requires explicit identity in order to redraw the DOM elements successfully.  I haven't really noticed this behavior outside a `<form>`, however, so there must be some interaction there.

at any rate...  Angular2 is awesome.  Carry on.  Nothing more to see here :)

Here's an updated plunk that functions as one would expect

https://plnkr.co/edit/g8fDquNgUY9MYoget8O4

the elements I changed in my example above are as follows.

```
<div class="form-group" *ngFor="let item of items; let i=index; trackBy:itemIdentity">
```

...

```
itemIdentity(index, item) {
console.log("index:{i}, item:{s}", index, item)
return index;
}
```

Comment: Weird, I just read another answer for tracking boolean changes to redraw elements in the DOM and thought of this question. Glad to see you were able to put the pieces together and find a solution. Still seems like unexpected behavior as the array itself is changing (whole new object!).